# Sorting list elements is not done

Tags: sorting, xamarin.android

I have a list. I want to sort elements of this but the list is not sorted.

```
    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> imageNames;
    imageNames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ();
    imageNames.Add("z");
    imageNames.Add("t");
    imageNames.Add("r");
    imageNames.Add("a");
    Java.Util.Collections.Sort(imageNames);
    Toast.MakeText(this, imageNames[0] + " " + imageNames[1] + " " + imageNames[2] + " " + imageNames[3], ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**System.Collections.Generic.List** is a class of C# . If you want to sort the list , you could invoke the line like following

```
imageNames.Sort();  // Ascending order

imageNames.Reverse();// Reverse order , you will get a Descending order
```